# Upload files into IIS via WCF + permissions for upload folder

Tags: wcf, iis

I have written a WCF client / server in order to send files from client to service.

I host the service inside a console APP initially and everything works fine.

But when I try to host within IIS I get an exception. Is there some special permissions that need to be given to the folder where I try to upload files.

I read a blog which said we need to specify NTFS permissions for the folder. But how do we specify them ?

Can someone help me with this ?

thanks

Comment: You need to grant write permission to the folder you're uploading in to the process running the web app.  You can do that by right-clicking on the folder in Windows Explorer, selecting properties, then selecting the security tab, then you can set the permissions for various accounts.

Comment: Double-check the identity the App Pool is running under - it might not be Network Service.

Comment: What is the exception you get?

Comment: @Tim now it works fine.. I got it up and running after the prev modifications.. sorry for the delay.. file transfer works for small  files.. but for 6MB files I need to see where its going wrong.. same 4-5MB file works fine with Console Host..

Comment: Glad it works for you.  I'm not that familiar with using SSL, but you'll need to set the transport security on the service's binding.  Might be easier to post that as a separate, new question.

Comment: @Tim got it up and running with this one <system.web> <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" /> <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="9999999"/> </system.web> ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to grant write permission to the process (account) running the web app for the folder you're uploading to. You can do that by right-clicking on the folder in Windows Explorer, selecting properties, then selecting the security tab, then you can set the permissions for various accounts.

If you're having problems for files greater in size than 6 MB you may need to tweak either the IIS file upload size limits.

Comment: thanks for your help.. i got lesser points hence cannot upvote.

Comment: You're welcome - keep asking questions (and try answering some as well) and you'll start picking up reputation.  Welcome to SO. :)